# How to test whether AWS elastic load balancer is working?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-load-balancer

How to test whether AWS elastic load balancer is working properly or not? Is there any test or thing with which we can verify it?

Regards

Comment: Your application's external IP address is IP address of ELB. If you app is working. Now if you need to check if a specific instance is healthy, you need to check heath checks

Answer (score 4):

To check the web load balancer, you can simply create two different web pages with the same filename on two servers.

Server 1: index.html

```
<html><body>This is server 1</body></html>
```

Server 2: index.html

```
<html><body>This is server 2</body></html>
```

Then you browse the webpage with the public IP address that load balancer provided.
When you see "This is server 1", you are connecting to server 1, vice versa.

Under the load balancer configuration page, you can see how many instances are running.
[image: server status]

Comment: ELB does not use Elastic IP addresses.

Comment: You'll need to perform your test using more than one client computer. ELB will keep sending requests to the same EC2 instance that originate from the same remote IP. Meaning, if you keep refreshing your browser on the same computer, it won't jump between EC2 instances. You need to try on another computer to get a different EC2 instance.

Comment: Yes Matt, I will modify my answer for that.